# Dynamically Referencing PivotTable Data

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2016

I am trying to reference a Pivot Table that has months for columns and years for rows. The following formula works just fine. The problem is that I have to edit the formula for each cell I'm using it in.

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Amount",'Distribution Data'!$A$4,"Months",8,"Years",2016)
```

I have a cell that has the month in question in mm/dd/yyyy format. I tried using a reference to that cell as follows. A2 is 8/31/2016

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Amount",'Distribution Data'!$A$4,"Months",month(a2),"Years",year(a2))
```

Unfortunately, all that returned was 0. I tried using Text() and Value() to reformat the number but nothing worked. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. It turns out that the data in A2 was not properly formatted. Excel was reading Aug 16 as 8/16/2018. Problem resolved.